# how to avoid header in list view appearing each time in Android

Tags: android

I have a list view which populates a table on a button click.
Also i have given a Header in first row. the problem is that each time when i click the button, The header is again appearing on next row as shown in below pic. How to avoid this.
[image]

The header code is given below.

```
View header = (View)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.header, null);
        credView.addHeaderView(header);
```

Comment: Dont add header inside the listview instead add the header above list view.

Comment: add more code. Base on what you put hard to gues where is the problem.

Comment: somewhere in the getView() you are not setting the header properly. show us the code